# heroku can't deploy but it's not any error message?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, web, webpack

https://github.com/unnhao/ReactRealTimeChatTraining

i deploy to heroku, it didn't occur any error at build log

but when i want to access this https://moutalk.herokuapp.com/
it display Application error

i test for github

git clone 
npm install
npm start

but it can run!!!

what's happen???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using the port `3000` but you should actually change it to

`var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;` and deploy it again..

for more details on how to deploy on heroku check this tutorial

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-app-to-heroku